# Display three lists in one Android activity by swiping or selecting an arrow button

Tags: android

I have 15 data items in JSON. I want to display 6 items in an Android `gridview`, 6 items in another view, and another 3 items in a third view in **one activity only** on swipe or selecting an arrow towards right in Android. How to do this?

Comment: @GrovindR Welcome to StackOverflow. I have edited your question to make it more readable. Please make adjustments if I did not understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `TableLayout` and than collapse some columns `onClick` ?

Let say you got 6 items in a row on your screen,
and show only the first 3 items. (start with `collapseColumns="3,4,5"`)

**example:**

TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/MyTable"
android:collapseColumns="3,4,5">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_black"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_black"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_black"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_white"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_white"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_white"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="previous"
    android:id="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="next"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

</TableLayout>
```

**And then inside your Activity:**

```
private TableLayout mTableLayout;
```

and in `onCreate()`

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(0,true);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(1,true);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(2,true);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(3,false);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(4,false);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(5,false);
    }
});

findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(0,false);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(1,false);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(2,false);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(3,true);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(4,true);
        mTableLayout.setColumnCollapsed(5,true);
    }
});
```

Really dunno if this is the best/easiest way, but it works ;)

**Screenshots:**

On Start (or clicked Next)
[image: On Start]

Clicked Previous:
[image]

**Hope this will help you out, good luck ;)**

Comment: my data can be in N numbers i don know how much is data length and position. So i have to check length than set in gridview 6 item in one view and rest again 6 item in another

Comment: @GovindR you can do all this stuff dynamic, add data dynamic (remember how much) and than show what you want and hide what you want, and when button is pressed show next items and hide previous items, and so on...